# SVN : While committing files automatically unzips and missing several files

Tags: linux, svn

**SVN Problem**

> While committing files

- automatically unzips
- several files missing for large data (for than 15 MB)

Environment

- For Server # Server SVN
- and  client side CornerStone2 (MAC OS X)

**Edit**: I want to commit zipped archives, which have to be unzipped and extracted files will appear in single commit

Comment: Question problem: this is a poorly asked, seems to be off-topic.  Environment: this site.

Comment: @Zoredache Please help me to make the question to a better one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If question can be expanded into something like

> I want to commit zipped archives, which have to be unzipped and
>   **extracted files** will appear in single commit

answer will be "You can't do it - pre-commit hooks **must not change** content of transaction body"

If you can agree on additional commit into repo (+1 to every you commit with zips) you can try to build post-commit hook, which:

- Store committed archives in some temporary location
- Unzip files
- `svn co` unzipped files
- Clean-up working dir

Comment: I have edited my question